# How to use parse paste-from-excel to copy blank values into numeric values in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy-paste

It requires special logic to convert the blank values from the copied Excel data into 0 values.
There is a parse function from the npm (paste-from-excel) package that I use.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import parse from "paste-from-excel";
const PasteFromExcel = () => {
    const dataPoint = [
        {
            "point_id": 1,
            "point_name": "HEADER",
            "point_unit": "mm/sec",
            "point_value": 0,
        },
        {
            "point_id": 2,
            "point_name": "BODY",
            "point_unit": "mm/sec",
            "point_value": 0,
        },
        {
            "point_id": 1,
            "point_name": "TOP",
            "point_unit": "mm/sec",
            "point_value": 0,
        },
        {
            "point_id": 1,
            "point_name": "BOTTOM",
            "point_unit": "mm/sec",
            "point_value": 0,
        }
    ];

    const [dataPoints, setDataPoints] = useState(dataPoint);

    const handleInput = (e, index) => {
        const newInputs = [...dataPoints];
        newInputs[index].point_value = e.target.value;
        setDataPoints(newInputs);
    }

    const handlePaste = (i, elm, e) => {
        parse(e);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {dataPoints && dataPoints.map((res, i) => (
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{res.point_name}</td>
                            <td>{res.point_unit}</td>
                            <td>
                            <input
                                size="small"
                                type="number"
                                value={res.point_value}
                                autoComplete="off"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    handleInput(e, i);
                                }}
                                onPaste={(e) => {
                                    handlePaste(i, res, e);
                                }}
                            />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PasteFromExcel;
```

Meaning what if the user copies 4 rows of data, then the first and second rows are empty?

1. How to convert the empty value to 0?
2. How to replace the copied values containing commas (,) to dots (.) ?